# How can I use my database in a container after push the container into Dockerhub?

Tags: database, docker

I'm trying to save a database into one container. How can I save my database when I push the container to Dockerhub?

Comment: Do you mean to save *data* or the *database program* itself?

Comment: I want to save _data_. Actually, I used pymongo to create "mydatabase" and save it into mongodb container. When I push the container into Dockerhub and  pull it in another computer, I use mongo shell to check but there is no 'mydatabase'.

Comment: Docker Hub images never contain _data_; you generally need to distribute or initialize that separately.  The linked question describes several ways to do this with MongoDB.